# How to format some numbers in a string in PHP?

Tags: php

I have string :

```
HAMMER FORGED (5.400PCE-2,340Kg-6.000M3-DANGER TYPE 2)
```

and want format that string to

```
HAMMER FORGED (5,40PCE-2.340,00Kg-6M3-DANGER TYPE 2)
```

Each number I know I can use `number_format()`, but how to extract those numbers and put it back to the right place?

The pattern is fixed: `goods name (alpha num)` following by attributes `([qty][unit]-[weight]Kg-[volume]M3-type)`, lenght of character dynamic

Comment: `(5.400PCE-2,340Kg-6.000M3-DANGER TYPE 2)` and `(5,40PCE-2.340,00Kg-6M3-DANGER TYPE 2)` totally different i meant some of zeros added extra... is that typo error?

Comment: Please show a couple more sample input strings and your expected result so that we can see how your input data may vary.

Comment: This string can change or it will ALWAYS have the same size / pattern?

Comment: the pattern is fixed, goods name (alpha num) following by attributes ([qty][unit]-[weight]Kg-[volume]M3-type), lenght of character dynamic

Comment: And can you change your data BEFORE building your string? For example if you know that `qty = 5.400` but you need `qty = 5,40`, just replace `.` by `,` and remove a `0`, no? Because if each value of your pattern can have different value (for example `qty = 5.400` or `qty = 12.400`) you can't make a "static" script that replace the value in your orignal string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution with `preg_replace_callback()`.  It's a bit convoluted because you need to also capture the substrings between your float values.

the digital matches are:

1. stripped of commas (where necessary)
2. converted to `float` values
3. reformatted by `number_float()` (as desired)

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0ea623a51fd6a3570e1922dddacff5f8a0f67871))

```
$string = 'HAMMER FORGED (5.400PCE-2,340Kg-6.000M3-DANGER TYPE 2)';

echo preg_replace_callback(
    '~\(([\d.]+)([A-Z]+-)([\d,.]+)(Kg-)([\d.]+)~',
    function($m) {
        return 
            "(".
            number_format((float)$m[1], 2, ",", ".").
            "$m[2]".
            number_format((float)str_replace(",", "", $m[3]), 2, ",", ".").
            "$m[4]".
            number_format((float)$m[5], 0);
    },
    $string);
```

Output:

```
HAMMER FORGED (5,40PCE-2.340,00Kg-6M3-DANGER TYPE 2)
```

[Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/IfQfw7/1)

Here are the matches that relate to the `$m` array that `preg_replace_callback()` generates:

```
Full match  14-37   `(5.400PCE-2,340Kg-6.000`
Group 1.    15-20   `5.400`
Group 2.    20-24   `PCE-`
Group 3.    24-29   `2,340`
Group 4.    29-32   `Kg-`
Group 5.    32-37   `6.000`
```

Comment: it helps.. thank you... but where is the index come from? I see five group (...) in array supposedly index 0-4?

Comment: @AnggaAriWijaya I added a bit more explanation to my answer. `$m[0]` is the fullstring match, but I don't use that element in my replacement callback.